# How do I keep track of which icon is currently selected instead of multiple icons at a time

Tags: html, css, angular

So, I am trying to get just one icon stay selected, I need to rewrite my function in the .ts file such that it ensures that when one icon is selected, only that icon changes color and the others are at default.If I select home only home icon changes color, if I select more, the home icon goes back to default while the more icon changes. Right now if I select one icon after the other, they all change color unless I refresh. Any help please?

.html

```
<div class="footer-container">
    <div class="nav-icon-container">
        <div [class.selected]="isHomeSelected" (click)="goToHome()">
            <mat-icon class="icon-container"> home</mat-icon>
        </div>
        <div [class.selected]="isProfileSelected" (click)="goToProfile()">
            <mat-icon class="icon-container" svgIcon="user"></mat-icon>
        </div>
        <div [class.selected]="isMessagesSelected" (click)="goToMessages()">
            <mat-icon class="icon-container">message</mat-icon>
        </div>
        <div [class.selected]="ismoreSelected" (click)="goToMore()">
            <mat-icon class="icon-container">more_horiz</mat-icon>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.ts

```
isHomeSelected = false;
goToHome() {
  this.isHomeSelected = true;
  this.router.navigate(['home']);
}

isProfileSelected = false;
goToProfile() {
  this.isProfileSelected = true;
  if(this.currentUser){
    this.router.navigate(['profile/'+this.currentUser.uid]);
  } else {
  this.router.navigate(['signin', {params:'/profile/'+this.currentUser.uid}]);
  } 
}

isMessagesSelected = false;
goToMessages() {
  this.isMessagesSelected = true;
  if(this.currentUser){
    this.router.navigate(['messages']);
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['signin', {params: '/messages'}]);
  } 
}

ismoreSelected = false;
goToMore() {
  this.ismoreSelected = true;
  return true
}
```

.css

```
.selected {
  color: #ff3588;
}
```

Comment: As per ur current setup you would need to set other fields to false like in `goToHome()` add `this.isProfileSelected = false;` etc.

Comment: OK, I don't actually want the other icons to remain constantly false. I meant, if I select home only home icon changes color, if I select more, the home icon goes back to default while the more icon changes. Right now if I select one icon after the other, they all change color unless I refresh

Comment: Yep, so similarly what u do in `goToHome` do the same in `goToProfile` and set `this.isHomeSelected=false`. Hope u getting my point.

Comment: Works pretty well, but looks too repetitive, I am working on a cleaner way to write it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array and loop through the "links" and change the `selected` class based on which is clicked (neatly), but since you are using varying icon solution (with svgIcon in the mix), it would seem it's maybe easier to add `ngClass` and the click event on each and every item in your list. So that would would look like the following, where we use `ngClass` to toggle the class, and we use an unique string (in this case), which we assign a variable, which defines which "link" would be active. This variable doesn't necessary need to exist in the TS file, but use one if you want to have an initial "link" chosen.

So modify your code to such:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedLink === 'link1'}" (click)="goToHome(); selectedLink = 'link1'">
  <mat-icon class="icon-container"> home</mat-icon>
</div>
<div [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedLink === 'link2'}" (click)="goToProfile(); selectedLink = 'link2'">
  <mat-icon class="icon-container" svgIcon="user"></mat-icon>
</div>
<div [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedLink === 'link3'}" (click)="goToMessages(); selectedLink = 'link3'">
  <mat-icon class="icon-container">message</mat-icon>
</div>
<div [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedLink === 'link4'}" (click)="goToMore(); selectedLink = 'link4'">
  <mat-icon class="icon-container">more_horiz</mat-icon>
</div>
```

Maybe use some better names though ;)

Here's a demo: **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-78qggf?file=app/input-overview-example.html)**

Comment: Thank you. I will love to go with this

Comment: Great, glad to hear it was helpful! :)